# Ruby On Rails: collection_select with ajax filtering the index page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to introduce a `collection_select` into my Projects index page that would filter out the projects to only display the projects managed by a certain user.

```
#projects model
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :manager_user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'manager_id'
end

#users model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
has_many :managed_projects, class_name: 'Projects', foreign_key: 'manager_id'
end

#index method in projects_controller
def index 
   if params[:user]
      @projects = Project.order(created_at: :desc).where(manager_id: params[:user]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)   
   else
      @projects = Project.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
   end

   respond_to do |format|
   format.html 
   format.js 
   end
  end

#projects index view
h1>Projects</h1>
<div class="filter">
    <%= label :manager_id, "Manager" %><br>
    <%= collection_select :project, :manager_id, User.all, :id, :username %>
</div> 
<div class="sort_paginate_ajax">
<%= render 'projects' %>
</div>
```

The partial projects contains the table listing the projects.

```
#index.js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.sort_paginate_ajax').html("<%= escape_javascript(render ("projects")) %>")
$("#notice").fadeOut(1000);

});
```

How can I accept what the user selects from the collection and re render the projects partial based on that selection to display projects for that manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to trigger an event for that to happen. The document ready is only firing once. Attach an event handler to your select element, and make an Ajax call to get the new data once the change is fired.

```
$('select.your-select').change(function() {
  $.ajax({
     url: '...',
     success: function(response) {
       // Take this new data and update the page
       $('.sort_paginate_ajax').html(response);
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I already have pagination with ajax in place and this seems to be interfering with it, by "select.your-select" do you mean I have to put there what the user selected? I assume something must be added to the collection_select ?

Comment: That's a jQuery selector to get the select. You need someway of targeting that select element. In your erb, add an html class or id to it by that. So, $('#id-of-element') or $('.class-of-element')

Comment: Ah I see I already have that as <div class="filter">, my problem remains is that how would the ajax call know what manager_id it was the user selected and send it to the index page to filter it accordingly.

Comment: Ah yes, take a look at jQuery's docs on sending data: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. Basically, you'll simply add the value of that select to the request. It's just as if you're submitting a form.